libglut.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I had wxDragon installed on my Ubuntu 22.04 previously and it worked perfectly. Now, I upgraded my Ubuntu to 24 version and I'm getting the following error:
wxDragon: error while loading shared libraries: libglut.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Thanks for your help.
